# Group by month and year but include the previous day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with data like the below and I am trying to group the data by both the month, year and the last day of the previous month. It is not always T-1 day.

Have already grouped the data by month and year but am stuck how to include the last day of the previous month in this query. Am sure that there is a better way instead of group by id and get the max date for each month. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
  select 
    ID,
    last_day(to_date('01' || to_char(DATA_DATE,'mm') || to_char(DATA_DATE,'yyyy'),'ddmmyyyy')) as DATA_DATE,
    SUM(GS_PX_AMT)
  from xxx
  group by ID, last_day(to_date('01' || to_char(DATA_DATE,'mm') || to_char(DATA_DATE,'yyyy'),'ddmmyyyy'))
```

[image: data]

Comment: Please elaborate.  Do you want the last day of a month to be in two different groups?  Or to be assigned to the next month?  Simple sample data and desired results -- as a text table -- are really useful.  Also, is there only one row per day?  If not, are all records taken?

Comment: The last day of a month to be grouped together with the next month. i.e  30 Mar 2018 with the whole of Apr's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the last day of a month in the *next* group, then use `lead()`:

```
select id,
       to_char(next_data_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
       sum(GS_PX_AMT)
from (select xxx.*,
             lead(data_date, 1, data_date) over (partition by id order by data_date) as next_data_date
      from xxx
     ) x
group by id, to_char(next_data_date, 'YYYY-MM');
```

If you want to include the last date *and* double count it, then you can also use window functions:

```
select id,
       to_char(data_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
       ( sum(GS_PX_AMT) +
         sum(case when yyyymm_seqnum = 1 then prev_amt else 0
             end)
       ) as double_counted_sum
from (select xxx.*,
             lag(GS_PX_AMT) over (partition by id order by data_date) as prev_amt,
             row_number() over (partition by id, to_char(next_data_date, 'YYYY-MM') order data_date) as yyyymm_seqnum
      from xxx
     ) x
group by id, to_char(data_date, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    ID,
    last_day(add_months(data_date,-1)) as DATA_DATE,
    SUM(GS_PX_AMT)
  from xxx
  group by ID, last_day(add_months(data_date,-1))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how the code answers the question improves its long-term value. It also helps avoid having your answer down-voted or flagged as low quality. See [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).